# How to select multiple records in sql matching a criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to select multiple records matching a field value. E.g.

```
ID ---- REGION
--------------
01 ---- NORTH
02 ---- SOUTH
03 ---- NORTH
04 ---- WEST
```

I want to select all IDs that are in region NORTH. The result I want in an array is {01,03}

How to do this in MYSQL and PHP?

Comment: What have you got so far? Surely this must be more complex than `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 10`

Comment: no that only returns all fields of the first matching record

Comment: Sorry, the code highlighting colouring your data as if it was a comment totally threw me there, first glanced your data as "north, south, east, west" - `select id from table where region ='NORTH'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE REGION = 'NORTH'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$IDs = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $IDs[] = $row["ID"]
    }
} 

$conn->close();

var_dump($IDs);
```

Comment: Op says he wants an array with the values in, not echoing them.. this answer could easily be improved to meet that requirement